# maven:doesn't match any artifact

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start

We use Maven & codehaus.mojo's webstart-maven-plugin for building the jnlp file.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.webstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk16</exclude>
              <exclude>org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </dependencies>
          <jnlp>
            <outputFile>Vector.jnlp</outputFile>
            <mainClass>com.rieter.launch.VAESRun</mainClass>
          </jnlp>
          <sign>
            <keystore>${basedir}/lib/vectorKeyStore</keystore>
            <keypass>******</keypass>
            <storepass>*****</storepass>
            <alias>***</alias>
            <verify>true</verify>
          </sign>
          <unsignAlreadySignedJars>true</unsignAlreadySignedJars>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

When we start the build then the follow error occurs:

```
    [maven] [INFO] --- webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:jnlp (default-cli) @ vector ---
[maven] [ERROR] pattern: org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk16 doesn't match any artifact.
[maven] [ERROR] pattern: org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16 doesn't match any artifact.
[maven] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[maven] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[maven] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[maven] [INFO] Total time: 1:38.950s
[maven] [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 30 16:32:09 CEST 2017
[maven] [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/34M
[maven] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[maven] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo.webstart:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:jnlp (default-cli) on project vector: At least one specified dependency is incorrect. Review your project configuration. -> [Help 1]
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.
Cheers Martin

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I thought codehaus was no longer valid. Aren't we suppose to use other sources? anyone?

Comment: *"Many thanks for any suggestions."* Based on the inquiry of @QBrute I'd suggest you ask a question. Every **Q** & A thread on this Q&A site should have one. Presuming the question is along the lines of *"How to resolve this resource error and do a clean build?"*.. I note the error seems to relate to `<exclude>org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk16</exclude>`. If maven claims a resource cannot be located, why exclude it at all? Try removing that line and report back the result.

Comment: The codehaus part is now located here: http://www.mojohaus.org/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask a question. How I can fix that error:pattern: org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk16 doesn't match any artifact. Andrew Thompson: Yes I did, and the error goes but then the rest of the webstart task went wrong.